# Function not defined error when calling from another function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am calling a function from inside another function like this:

```
methods: {
  selectStep: function (id) {
    ...
  }

  controlStep: function () {
    selectStep(1);
    ...
  }
}
```

but all I get is an error saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: selectStep is not defined
```

Do you have any idea about what could be happening here?

Comment: try: `this.selectStep(1)`

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is trying to execute a function from the `window` object or from whatever context was declared that object `methods`.

**You need to call that function as follow:**

```
this.selecteStep(1);
```

Further, you need to separate those methods/functions using comma `,`

```js
const methods = {
  selectStep: function (id) {
    console.log('called!', id);
  },
  controlStep: function () {
    this.selectStep(1);
  }
}

methods.controlStep();
```

Answer (score 2):

> You have to use this.anotherMethodName

```
<template>
    ...

    <button @click="callMethod"></button>

    ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            firstMethod() {
                console.log('called')
            },
            callMethod() {
                this.firstMethod()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```